# Кнопка Start/Stop на JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

По заданию нужно сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Start" она изменяла свою подпись на "Stop" и наоборот.
Пытался сделать так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'stop');
    $(this).val('Stop');
  });
  $('#stop').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'stop');
    $(this).val('Stop');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="start" value="Start" />
```

Не работает.

Как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#start');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  btn.value = (btn.value == 'Start' ? 'Stop' : 'Start');
})
```

```html
<input type="button" id="start" value="Start" />
```

Comment: Спасибо! Можно будет таким же самым образом повесить на нее запуск определенного процесса?

Comment: @Денис Конечно, добавить то что нужно после изменения названия кнопки. Не за что)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите менять только сообщение, то зачем же меняете еще и `ID` кнопки?

Наиболее простой и, вероятно, понятный для вас код будет таким

```js
$("#start").click(function(){      
   var v = $(this).val();
   
   switch(v){
      case 'start': v = 'stop';  break;
      case 'stop':  v = 'start'; break;
   }
   
   $(this).val(v);      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="start" value="start"/>
```

Хотя, это возможны и более короткие варианты записи, приводящие к тому же эффекту.

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
   var msgs = ['stop', 'start'];
   var v = $(this).val();
   $(this).val( msgs[ +(v == 'stop') ] );
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
   var cfg = { stop: 'start', start: 'stop' };
   var v = $(this).val();
   $(this).val( cfg[v]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="start"/>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="start"/>
```

и прочие вариации, например, используя data-атрибуты

Comment: Спасибо! Кроме смены названия нужно будет сделать запуск определенного процесса, думал через id идентифицировать старт и стоп)

Comment: для этого используют `data-` атрибуты

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с созданием класса `Toggle`

```js
function Toggle(values) {
  //сырой массив
  this.raw = values;
  //текущий индекс
  this.head = 0;
  //итератор
  this.iter = function() {
     this.head = (this.head < this.raw.length - 1) ? this.head + 1 : 0;
  }
  //получить текущее значение массива
  this.getCurrent = function () {
     return this.raw[this.head];
  }
}


window.onload = function () {
  
  //объявление
  var tog = new Toggle(["start","stop"]);
  //добавление элемента, это можно было сделать при инициалиации но здесь оно нужно для наглядности
  tog.raw.push("pause");
  
  
  var bind = document.getElementById("bind");
  bind.value = tog.getCurrent();
  bind.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //итерируемся
    tog.iter();
    bind.value = tog.getCurrent();
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="" id="bind">
```